# How can we solve version conflicts between Microsoft Graph 5.44.0 and Microsoft Identity Client 4.59.0?

Tags: c#, .net, azure-ad-msal

*Microsoft Graph 5.44.0* depends indirectly on *Microsoft.IdentityModel.Abstractions Version 7.3.1*.
For authentification we also use *Microsoft.Identity.Client Version 4.59.0*. This library, however, depends on *Microsoft.IdentityModel.Abstractions Version 6.22.0*.
This gives us a library conflict.
Now there is a way out of that - the binding redirects in the created app.config file.

Unfortunately this way out does not work for my project, as I am delivering a DLL which serves as plugin for another application - and I cannot control this target application's .exe.config file!
So is there a way out of this dependency conflict?

With the previous major MS Graph version the problem was even worse, as here *Microsoft.Graph Version 4.54.0* already indirectly depends on *Microsoft.Identity.Client Version 4.49.1* which in turn depends on *Microsoft.IdentityModel.Abstractions Version 6.22.0*, while other transitive dependencies of MS Graph 4 introduced a dependency on *Microsoft.IdentityModel.Abstractions Version 6.26.1* - version conflict again.

Is there a way out of this problem?
As far as I can see, the Microsoft.Identity.Client library is the way to go to use the "Integrated Windows Authentification" flow, which is a requirement for our library.

EDIT: As it was not clear what the error was, I will try to clarify the problem (I will state it for my experiments with MS Graph 4.54, as here the error is easier to understand)

- I am building a library, not the full application.
- The application is dynamically loading my library during runtime, i.e. it is loaded as a plugin.
- And then, as soon as I try to use methods from Microsoft.Identity.Client, an exception is thrown because the Method *Microsoft.Identity.Client.PublicClientApplicationBuilder.Create* requires *Microsoft.IdentityModel.Abstractions, Version=6.22.0.*.
  This is true, because successful compilation requires from me to use Microsoft.IdentityModel.Abstractions, Version=6.26.1*.

As we are not providing the full application here, but only a plugin, binding redirects do not help us here - we have not the full control over the application configuration.

Does this make the problem clearer?

Comment: What is the error?  Normally with conflicts you need to specify the full path of the library including the namespaces like System.Xml.Linq.XElement instead of just XElement.

Comment: Considering you haven't given any details on what the error is, this question is unanswerable as it currently stands.

Comment: `is there a way out of this dependency conflict` yes, upgrade to .NET (Core). Probably not very helpful, but will definitely work and you'll never have to worry about binding redirect stupidity ever again.

Comment: Updating to .NET Core is unfortunately not possible - we are writing plugins for a .NET classic application, so that's what we have to use here.